# Finding and replacing within selection is replacing the whole document

Tags: vba, vbscript, ms-word

I'm trying to iterate through all the paragraphs which are not within a table and highlighting the text as such:

```
'Iterate All Paragraphs
Dim p
objWord.Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = finalColor
For Each p In objDoc.Paragraphs
    p.Range.Select
    If Not objWord.Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        With objWord.Selection.Range.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Highlight = False
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.Highlight = True
          .Execute , , , , , , True, wdFindStop, , , wdReplaceAll
        End With
    End If
Next
```

The condition `objWord.Selection.Information(wdWithInTable)` works just fine, however the Find/Execute is replacing all non highlighted text throughout the document, even if within tables.

Any guesses as why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really think you should be using the Find object for this, but if you insist, perhaps you should store the Selection.Range in a variable first, then use the .Find property of that.

I would do it something like this:

```
Sub HighlightNonTableParagraphs()
    Dim oDocument As Document
    Dim oParagraph As Paragraph
    Dim oRange As range

    Set oDocument = ActiveDocument

    For Each oParagraph In oDocument.Paragraphs
        With oParagraph.range
            If Not .Information(wdWithInTable) Then
                .HighlightColorIndex = wdBlue
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```